# Size of a linear image of a cube in $\mathbb{Z}^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Suppose that we have an element $v = (v_1, \dots, v_d) \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ such that $\gcd(v_1, \dots, v_d) = 1$. Then $v$ is contained in some base of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ (seen as a free-abelian group or a free module over $\mathbb{Z}$). In particular, there exists a regular integer matrix $A \in \mathop{GL}_d(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $A(v) = (1, 0, \dots, 0)$.

My question is the following: assuming that $|v_1| + \dots + |v_d| = n$, what is the smallest $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ (taken over all possible matrices $A$) such that the image $A\left([-1, 1]^d\right)$ is contained in the cube $[-\ell, \ell]^d$? I care about asymptotics of $\ell(n)$ up to multiplicative constant.

Comment: Do you have any partial answers for when $d = 2$ or $3$?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer yes, in dimension 2 this is not too hard. Following Bézout's identity, there are $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x v_1 + y v_2 = 1$, $|x| \leq |v_2|$ and $|y| \leq |v_1|$. A good candidate for the matrix $A$ is $\begin{pmatrix} x &y \\ n_2 & -n_1\end{pmatrix}$. One can then see that $A([-1,1]^2) \subseteq [-|x|-|y|, |x|+|y|]\times[-|v_1| - |v_2|,|v_1|+|v_2] \subseteq [-n,n]^2$. So in this case, $\ell(n) = n$.
I'm having hard time generalising this to higher dimensions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d$ is fixed and you care about the asymptotic behavior in $n$, then you cannot do better than linear bound because you can take the vector $(p,p,\dots,p,q)$ where $p\approx n$ is prime and $qk\equiv 1\mod p$ for some $k\approx n/2$, so the first row has to be large. Keeping this in mind, you can easily arrange the other rows of size $n$ by putting $0,\dots,0,v_{j+1},-v_j,0,\dots,0$ there (if all $v_j\ne 0$; otherwise arrange them so that the first few aren't and then do this until you hit the zeroes and add the diagonal of ones in the end).

Thus, the only problem is to come up with the first row of size comparable to $n$, i.e., with an integer vector $a$ such that $(a,v)=1$ and $|a|\le C(d)n$. The integer vectors with the property $(a,v)=1$ form a lattice in the corresponding hyperplane with determinant $\|v\|_2\le n$ and the minimal vector length $\ge 1$. Such a lattice cannot miss a ball of radius $C(d)n$, so the solution exists.

*Edit* Ah, yes, I should have mentioned the last step. Here goes.

We have a lattice $\Lambda$ given by $\langle a,v\rangle=0$ and you want the last $n-1$ rows to be a *basis* of that lattice. What I created is a set of short (length $\le n$) linearly independent vectors $a_1,\dots,a_{d-1}$ in $\Lambda$. But now just consider the lattices $\Lambda_k=\Lambda\cap L_k$ where $L_k={\rm span}(a_1,\dots,a_k)$. The basis in $\Lambda_1$ is just the primitive vector $a_1'$ in the direction of $a_1$ (so it is $\le n$). To get the basis in $\Lambda_2$, take the closest (in the Euclidean distance) to $L_1$ vector in $\Lambda_2$ that is not in $\Lambda_1$. Its distance from $L_1$ is at most $n$ (because $a_2$ competes). And its projection to $L_1$ can be brought below $|a_1'|\le n$ by adding $a_1'$ with appropriate integer coefficient. Thus we can have $|a_2'|\le 2n$. Now we have a basis in $\Lambda_2$ with the fundamental parallelogram of diameter $3n$. For $a_3'$ take the closest to $L_2$ vector in $\Lambda_3\setminus\Lambda_2$. The distance to $L_2$ is $\le n$ ($a_3$ competes) and the projection to $L_2$ can be brought into the fundamental parallelogram we constructed, so we get $|a'_3|\le 4n$ and the fundamental parallelepiped for $\Lambda_3$ of diameter $7n$. And so on. The final estimate is $2^dn$. It can, probably, be improved but I have to refresh my rather rusty knowledge of Geometry of Numbers to say how and to what. We all have read the same books anyway (Cassels, Rogers, & Co.), so you may also search the answer there yourself :-)

Comment: The first row can be constructed effectively: just take the Bézout's coefficients, i.e. $c_1 , \dots, c_d \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ such that $\sum_{i = 1}^d c_i v_i = \gcd(v_1, \dots, v_d) = 1$. Using a result of Havas (https://staff.itee.uq.edu.au/havas/1994mh.pdf Theorem 9) one can gets that $\sum_{i = 1}^d |c_i| \leq \frac{d}{2} n$.

Could you please expand the first paragraph about expanding the first row to the rest of the matrix?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this method does not work since the resulting matrix might not be invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Just writing it out for $d=3$ you get that the determinant is equal to $v_2$ and there is no assumption that $v_2 \in \{-1, 1\}$.

Comment: @MichalFerov Yep, I forgot to add the final step because I thought that your difficulty was the first row and concentrated on that :-)

Comment: @MichalFerov Is it clear now or you still have more questions? :-)

Comment: it still does not really make sense to me... Unless I'm missing something, $L_1 \subseteq L_2 \subseteq \dots \subseteq L_k \subseteq \Lambda$, so then $\Lambda_k = L_k$ and so in the end we just end up with a different basis for $L_k$. In case $\Lambda = L_k$ it's all good, but in that case I can just use the $a_j$'s. I guess you meant $\Lambda_i$ to be the maximal rank-$k$ subgroup of $\Lambda$ containing $L_i$. I'm not sure what is meant by the projections though - I do apologise for potentially stupid questions but my knowledge of lattices is virtually non-existent.

Comment: @MichalFerov $L_k$ is the span over $\mathbb R$ (a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$), not over $\mathbb Z$ (not a sublattice). The projection is just the usual orthogonal projection. Apologies for not answering earlier: I just haven't visited MO since late March :-)